# Как вывести определенное количество кнопок в боте?

Tags: python, selenium, telebot

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from keyboa import Keyboa

API_TOKEN = 'token'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def one_s(message):
    keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
    numbers = '1' , '2'
    keyboard.row(numbers)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет', reply_markup=keyboard)
bot.polling()

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_dict'
```

Хочу сделать так чтобы скрипт определял сколько элементов найдет парсер и выводил соответствующие количество кнопок, нигде не найду как это сделать, пытаюсь сделать через кортежи, получаю ошибки. Что можно сделать в этом случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно распаковать кортеж/список

```
keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
numbers = ('1' , '2')
keyboard.row(*numbers)
```